# QGIS 2.18 buffer

Tags: qgis, vector, buffer

I'm trying to use fixed distance buffer, and had a few questions. One, what units is the distance being measured in? I assumed meters, but after doing a test run it clearly isn't. And two, what is "Segments"? I checked the documentation, and it doesn't give any hints about either (I think this part of the documentation was never finished)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units depend on your layer CRS. You used a WGS84 layer, so the units are degrees. The segments-value is the number of segments used to approximate a quarter circle.